# What is the minimum legal requirement for logbook keeping in Ireland?

Tags: legal, logging

The question came up during a club event, and obviously we checked the regulations.

references:

- ["Amateur Station Licence Guidelines" page 22](https://www.comreg.ie/publication-download/amateur-station-licence-guidelines)

From this document the details in regards to required logbook keeping:

1. dates of transmission;
2. the times (in UTC standard time), during each day of the first and
   last transmissions from the Station and changes made to the
   frequency band, mode of emission or power;
3. frequency band of transmission;
4. mode of transmission;
5. power level (dBW or W);
6. initial calls ("CQ" calls) whether or not they are answered; and
7. the call-sign of licensed Amateur Stations with which
   communications have been established.

**All this is clear, except item 3.**

The question here is, what is meant by "*frequency band of transmission*"

1. the frequency, e.g. "7.123 MHz"
2. the band, e.g. "40m"
3. both the band and frequency, e.g. "7.123 MHz 40m"
4. either the band or frequency, e.g. "7.123 MHz" |or| "40m"

**My question:**

> What is ***minimum*** required here, in regards to "*frequency band of
>   transmission*" ?

*In my own interpretation of this, I would believe the requirement is logging the "band" as the minimum requirement, e.g "40 meter" or "40m"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm neither from Ireland nor involved in legal issues, so please take this answer with a grain of salt.

---

From the document you had linked I would argue that 'frequency band' can be referred to Annex A1.3 table 1 as that states:

> The `frequency bands` `specified in Table 1` below ...

So it's something like:

- 7100-7200 kHz

That corresponds also to my rf engineering point of view that a 'band' represents a frequency range and not a single frequency.

But as long as an abbreviation is unambiguous my personal guess is that it should be ok as well.